# Tumblr global tags as RSS

Tags: rss, tumblr

We can transform any individual site tags as rss by simply going to `[sites].tumblr.com/tagged/[tag]/rss` and we can also see global tags result by going to `tumblr.com/tagged/[tag]`

However, `tumblr.com/tagged/[tag]/rss` isn't a valid page. Is there any API or 3rd party service to transform the global tag into RSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible from Tumblr itself, but you might be able to use a 3rd party service like that offered by FiveFilters.org to create an RSS feed from the Tumblr global tag page: http://createfeed.fivefilters.org/

1. Enter web page URL: `http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/cat/`
2. Look for links inside HTML elements whose id or class attribute contains: `post_content`
3. Only keep links if link URL contains: `/post/`

Comment: It kinda works. Not as good as original Tumblr feeds where full content is available, but it did serve my purpose

Comment: This works and that's a great app by the way. But it doesn't let me extract the images from tumblr posts. Any ideas?